# Selenium ChromeDriver how to click elements with negative x,y pixel locations? C#

Tags: javascript, c#, css, google-chrome, selenium

I'm working with a website that has pop-up tables. For example, if a user hovers or clicks over a link, a small popup with a table of data appears. There are many of these links available on the same page. Extracting data from the tables involves sequentially opening and closing each popup by clicking the links in order.

Closing a popup involves clicking a small 'X' button in the top right corner of the popup. About 99% of the time, this is not an issue. However, about 1% of the time, the top of the popup will be above the screen, with a negative 'y' pixel location, hiding the close pop-up 'X' button - and, in turn, giving it a negative 'y' pixel location. With manual operations (moving the mouse by hand) I can resize the Chrome window and the popup will 'snap' back in to the window with at a very minimum a 'y' pixel location of zero.

I have not been able to replicate this manual re-centering of the pop-up using Selenium commands. The closest command that I can find is `MoveToElement` which works sometimes, but not others (I cannot fathom why I am seeing partial success, but that is a digression from this question).

As far as I can tell, Selenium will not allow me to interact with a element that has a negative x or y pixel location.

Here is what I am currently attempting, with limited success:

```
// example begins with pop-up already displayed. Data has been extracted.
// We are now ready to close the pop-up by clicking the 'X' button.

// here we move to the table, otherwise the detail popup close button will be off screen. Warning: this works with partial success. 

var actions = new Actions(Session.Driver);
actions.MoveToElement(table);
actions.Perform();

// Must close unless the popup may (or may not) cover the next link.
var closeButton = Session.Driver.FindElement(By.Id(id))
    .FindElements(By.CssSelector("a.cmg_close_button"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (closeButton != null)
{
    Wait.Until(d => closeButton.Displayed);

    if (closeButton.Location.Y < 0 || closeButton.Location.X < 0)
    {
        Log.Error("Could not close button. The popup displayed the close_button off-screen giving it a negative x or y pixel location.");
    }
    else
    {
        closeButton.Click();
    }
}
```

Please advise strategies for handling the negative x,y pixel location of the popup window.

I am using C# 4.6, Selenium 2.45, ChromeDriver (Chrome), and VS2015 CE IDE.

Comment: Why are you not trying using `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By)` which gives you clickable element with positive height and width..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur What is it about `.ElementToBeClickable()` that forces the element to be on the screen?

Comment: @Jeffc No it's just checking until element visible and enabled that's mean clickable..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur so if the element doesn't move, how does that fix OP's problem? It's just going to throw an exception once it times out because the element never becomes clickable.

Comment: @JeffC how can you say element never becomes clickable while OP implemented wait until visible??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur because OP stated that he can't click it only when the X,Y coords are < 0. So unless the method you suggest is going to move the element, it's not going to be clickable (still). All .ElementToBeClickable() does is to make sure the element exists and isn't disabled (which generally only applies to buttons). See the source: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/dotnet/src/support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs

Comment: @JeffC ok sir...thanks for suggestion... you are the legend... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the page doesn't correctly set the position of the popup when the link is close to a border of the view.

To overcome this issue, you could first scroll the targeted element toward to the center of the view before moving over it:

```
// scroll the link close to the center of the view
Session.Driver.ExecuteScript(
  "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);" +
  "window.scrollBy(-200, -200);" ,
  table);

// move the mouse over
new Actions(Session.Driver)
  .MoveToElement(table)
  .Perform();
```

Comment: IJavaScriptExecutor javaScriptExecutor = Session.Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
                    javaScriptExecutor?.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);" + "window.scrollBy(-200, -200);", table);

Comment: I had to change it to the above to get it working. I am currently executing a full test. It runs for a few hours. Fingers crossed...

Comment: Casting to `IJavaScriptExecutor` is only require when the driver is casted to the "IWebDriver" interface. With the base class: `RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  driver.ExecuteScript('...');`

Comment: This worked perfectly. However, counter-intuitively instead of "scrolling up" to get the element in place; I had to "scroll down" - all the way to the bottom of the page - and surprisingly the pop-up centered itself with positive-x and positive-y coordinates. A side note: ZOOMING OUT will not work and is a false hope. While the pop-up does become visible, Chromium will continue using x,y coordinates of elements at 100% zoom setting.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium was designed to only interact with elements that a user can. In most cases, this applies more to hidden elements on the page. You have a somewhat rare case, in my experience, in that your "hidden" element is off the page instead of `display:none`, etc.

One way around this is to use `IJavaScriptExecutor`. This will allow you to run JS code on the page. **NOTE**: If you are trying to stick to a strict user scenario, i.e. do only things a user can do, this is not for you. You will need to continue to investigate ways to bring that popup back on the screen.

I think if you alter your script, as below, it should work.

```
if (closeButton.Location.Y < 0 || closeButton.Location.X < 0)
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor jse = Session.Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", closeButton);
    // Log.Error("Could not close button. The popup displayed the close_button off-screen giving it a negative x or y pixel location.");
}
else
{
    closeButton.Click();
}
```

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I have no problem with people downvoting my answers, etc. if there is a good reason... and if there is a good reason, I would like to know what it is so I can correct it or at least respond to the disagreement.